# python manage.py shell nothing happening

Tags: python, django

I'n new to django and I'm practicing through Django's Documentation on setting up my first project.

All worked well until it asked to invoke the Python shell with the command `python manage.py shell`

As a result, nothing really happens apart from showing the following text:

Python 3.7.1 (v3.7.1:260ec2c36a, Oct 20 2018, 14:05:16) [MSC v.1915 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)

Could someone please help? I tried finding an answer in very different sources but no one has really answered it. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What did you expect to happen? You’re saying you don’t end up in the shell where you can type in commands?

Comment: Well I believe I should be able to explore the database API

Comment: Well, you’ll get a shell, a command prompt, a place to type in commands. Are you saying you can’t do that?

Comment: Make sure you're within your project directory and manage.py file is actually present in your path!

Comment: Please forgive my ignorance. I type it on cmd and nothing happens @deceze.

Comment: @Ronnie I used  'cd mysite' before so the file is there. No errors are presented. Just nothing happening in terms of a shell

Comment: Could you maybe upload a screenshot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is what exactly happens. Just start typing in shell you can see the result.
Do not expect any other screen to open.
If you want to exit from shell use exit() command.

I hope that helps.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

---

The `python manage.py shell` command opens an interactive shell (using IPython or bpython if available). It's used to run code with the django environment enabled. This means that if, for example, you want to try out some database queries you could:

```
>> from yourproject.yourapp.models import YourModel
>> YourModel.objects.all()
>> [<YourModel: 1>]
```